# how to check the required data in this php array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a response in below format. I am using laravel.
I want to check if there is street_number present or not despite of their `index` and if yes just print the `long_name`
similar I want to check if there is `route` in `types` of this array or not. if yes print route `long_name` and so on.

`dd($dataArray);` gives this response

```
array:3 [
  "html_attributions" => []
  "result" => array:15 [
    "address_components" => array:7 [
      0 => array:3 [
        "long_name" => "19"
        "short_name" => "19"
        "types" => array:1 [
          0 => "street_number"
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:3 [
        "long_name" => "Becket Street South"
        "short_name" => "Becket St S"
        "types" => array:1 [
          0 => "route"
        ]
      ]
      2 => array:3 [
        "long_name" => "senroy"
        "short_name" => "Slenroy"
        "types" => array:2 [
          0 => "locality"
          1 => "political"
        ]
      ]
]
```

I am looping like this

```
$newArray=[];
foreach($dataArray['result'] as $data){
//    check if street_number in array or not if yes push it value to new array
//same for other types as well

}
```

Comment: just check inside `types` via `in_array` so that you don't need to use a hardcoded index, it'll just check if `street_address` exists

Comment: i did this if (in_array('street_number', $data[$key]['types'])){
                // it gives error "Undefined index: types"
            }

Comment: but this is fine if (in_array('street_number', $data[0]['types'])). but i don't want to hardcode

Answer (score 2):

the inside of your foreach is problematic:
should be like this:

```php
foreach($dataArray as $key=> $data){
    if (in_array('street_number',$data['types'])) {
        
    }
}
```

because your types is already in *$data* inside the foreach. So you don't need to say $key again.

**Edit 1:**
found the problem. remove `isset($data[$key])` because it is always false. because the $key is returning 0,1,.... but $data keys are these three : 'long_name' , 'short_name' , 'types' . You can check by `dd($key)`

**Edit 2:**
After your latest update of the question, your foreach should be like this:

```php
foreach($dataArray['result']['address_components'] as $data){
    if (in_array('street_number',$data['types'])) {
        dd('should be here');
    }
}
```

Comment: not working:  if (isset($data[$key]) && in_array('street_number',$data['types'])) {
        dd('yes');
    }I have not got the yes  answer which means it was skipped

Comment: problem found and updated in the answer @David

Comment: message: "Undefined index: types"
got error

Comment: I just tested and got inside the loop. please check your $data. are you trying `$data[$key]['types']` or `in_array('street_number',$data['types'])` ?

Comment: Share `var_nump($data)` from the loop

Comment: hi sorry my mistake my loop is like this foreach($dataArray['result'] as $key=> $data){
    dd($data)} gives above output
        
    }

Comment: var_nump($data) give above output

Comment: can you please provide more of your logic code? above and below the foreach? @David

Comment: updated ,please refresh the page and check it

Comment: Honestly as long you do `dd($variableGivingWarning)` you should be able to figure out which array keys to use. Your top-level loop should start with `$dataArray['result']['address_components']` instead of `$dataArray['result']`

Comment: now that you showed us full array. we see that you missed `['address_components']` like Pablo said

Answer (score 0):

May this can help you

```
foreach ($data['result']['address_components'] as $val) {
    if(\Illuminate\Support\Arr::has($val, 'types') && in_array('street_number', $val['types'])) {
        echo "For Street Nu.";
    }else if(\Illuminate\Support\Arr::has($val, 'types') && in_array('route', $val['types'])) {
        echo "For Route";
    }
}
```